# How to let Netbeans know that a file was changed externally?

Tags: php, netbeans-8

- With Netbeans I create a new PHP .inc file in a project
- Then I let a MySQL query dump a PHP array with the content of a table and pipe it directly into this new file, overwriting it.
- When I open the file with Netbeans, the overwritten changes are not visible.

  This is a prototype and later I want to use the array to automatically initialise the application by using API.

How do I make Netbeans reread or re-index the changes that took place externally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation you need to do is "synchronise".

Right click on the file or the folder you want to synchronise in the project left panel, and click on "synchronise". Netbeans will analyse the files and ask you what to do for each of them. You can decide to upload, download or leave as it is... You can also have a diff to see the differences between remote and local files.
Hope it helps

Comment: This is the right answer although it first took me some time to understand what I did wrong. In my case the server and local code in GIT are both stored in the same computer (both desktop and server system). I don't use virtual server for this project. Although on the same system I simply forgot that local code is not equal the updated server code, even though they are on the same system. Downloading did the trick.